# So, I lost the entire Xcode Project for my app

Tags: xcode, app-store, project, app-store-connect

So I did something really stupid... I got a new MBP, and gave my old one to a friend. Before I did that, I transferred all of the contents of my big folders (Documents, Downloads, etc...) to my new Mac, and then I deleted the user on my old Mac. Unfortunately, I neglected to transfer the folder that contained the entire Xcode Project for my app that is currently on the App Store, as it wasn't in one of those folders, and I'm the only one who had it. The only way of being able to retrieve it that I thought of was that since I had to upload the binary to iTunes Connect to submit the app, Apple might still have it. Otherwise, I guess I'll have to completely start from scratch if I ever want to update it again. I just contacted Apple via iTunes Connect, but I was wondering if anyone has any idea of what I am able to do now, mainly, if Apple will actually give me all the files back. Thanks.

Comment: all software development should use a source revision control system (preferably with offsite secure storage). I sympathise with you; happened to me years ago (dark ages) at a company who didn't use SCC. It's a hard lesson, but once learned I doubt you'll make the same mistake twice.

Answer (score 4):

Any chance you've got a backup via [timemachine](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1427)?

Timemachine can't help you in the case of a fire (see http://github.com for what you can do about fires, hurricanes, tornadoes, volcanoes, or thieves), but maybe it can save your bacon right now. :)

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, you pretty much lost it. I'd recommend looking at some source control - for example [Github](https://github.com/). It's built into XCode, and Github is pretty cheap for Private Repositories, and free for public ones.

Answer (score 2):

You (nor Apple) won't be able to retrieve it from the binary.

No revision control system?!

Answer (score 1):

You wiped your data or only simply deleted?

Because, here is a possibility retrieve data from the HDD (or at least some parts) when only simply deleted them. Delete usually does not wipe the data.

If you can get your old HDD, you should:
- insert it into external usb-HDD enclosure
- attach to your new MAC
- make an image from it to one big file (with the command "dd") (assuming than your new HDD is bigger than your old)
- and with several tools you can "try" recover some data

every use of the old HDD drastically lowering the chance recovering something from it.